# Pre-Built (SEED Labs) Ubuntu 20.04 is behaving differently on my Machine

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2, docker, container

We are taking the Software Security and Web Security part of SEED Labs v2.0 as part of our Computer Security class.

I have completed all tasks under Software Security; however, I got stuck in the Web Security part.

The Web Security part typically involves Docker Containers to run the vulnerable, db, attack, etc servers.

Now, I use the Ubuntu 20.04 VM (with Oracle Virtual Box) provided by the SEED Labs, and my classmates use it too, and I set it up exactly as the manual did. However, when I get my Dockers up, I cannot access any of the websites that are included in the particular lab activity, while other VMs (from my classmates) can.

These are the things that I have already done and they DID NOT work:

1. Restart VM. Didnt work.
2. Stop and Remove all Docker images, delete the Lab Activity Folder, copy paste it again, and built the Dockers again and try. Nothing.
3. Remove the VM from Virtual Box, remove the Corresponding Files, add another fresh copy of the VM, try again. Still broken.
4. Reinstall Virtual Box, deleted every files associated with it, downloaded a new SEED Labs Ubuntu 20.04 image, tried that. Still broken.
5. Tried another VM provided by our class, broken there too.

Yes, I tried setting up the exact same way on another machine (classmate's), but it works fine there.

Here is what I am getting when visiting a webpage used for the lab:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at www.attacker32.com Port 80
```

^ Taken from the CSRF Lab Activity

My last resort is to Refresh-Reset my Windows, and hopefully that will fix it.

But can someone help me with this before I pull the trigger on that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How did you install docker, from Ubuntu app store? If so uninstall and follow instructions in official docker page.